# How to find root of evil in OracleXAException

Tags: java, oracle

In our java application We have got an exception like

```
   ERROR net.acs.sdd.pkop.bo.TreatmentMessageDispatcher - could not execute query
org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not execute query
    at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.handledNonSpecificException(SQLStateConverter.java:126)
    at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.convert(SQLStateConverter.java:114)
    at org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:66)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2231)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2125)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2120)
    at org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:401)
    at org.hibernate.hql.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:361)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:196)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1148)
    at org.hibernate.impl.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:102)
    at org.jbpm.pvm.internal.query.AbstractQuery.execute(AbstractQuery.java:88)
    at org.jbpm.pvm.internal.query.ProcessDefinitionQueryImpl.execute(ProcessDefinitionQueryImpl.java:65)
    at org.jbpm.pvm.internal.query.AbstractQuery.untypedList(AbstractQuery.java:64)
    at org.jbpm.pvm.internal.query.AbstractQuery.untypedUniqueResult(AbstractQuery.java:68)
    at org.jbpm.pvm.internal.query.ProcessDefinitionQueryImpl.uniqueResult(ProcessDefinitionQueryImpl.java:145)
    at org.jbpm.pvm.internal.repository.RepositorySessionImpl.findProcessDefinitionByKey(RepositorySessionImpl.java:143)
    at org.jbpm.pvm.internal.cmd.StartProcessInstanceInLatestCmd.execute(StartProcessInstanceInLatestCmd.java:57)
    at org.jbpm.pvm.internal.cmd.StartProcessInstanceInLatestCmd.execute(StartProcessInstanceInLatestCmd.java:37)
    at org.jbpm.pvm.internal.svc.DefaultCommandService.execute(DefaultCommandService.java:42)
    at org.jbpm.pvm.internal.tx.jta.JtaTransactionInterceptor.executeInExistingTx(JtaTransactionInterceptor.java:65)
    at org.jbpm.pvm.internal.tx.jta.JtaTransactionInterceptor.execute(JtaTransactionInterceptor.java:51)
    at org.jbpm.pvm.internal.tx.jta.JtaRetryInterceptor.executeWithoutRetry(JtaRetryInterceptor.java:56)
    at org.jbpm.pvm.internal.tx.jta.JtaRetryInterceptor.execute(JtaRetryInterceptor.java:48)
    at org.jbpm.pvm.internal.svc.EnvironmentInterceptor.execute(EnvironmentInterceptor.java:54)
    at org.jbpm.pvm.internal.svc.ExecutionServiceImpl.startProcessInstanceByKey(ExecutionServiceImpl.java:78)
    at net.acs.sdd.scvv.bo.BaseBusinessProcessor.startProcess(BaseBusinessProcessor.java:209)
    at net.acs.sdd.scvv.bo.BaseBusinessProcessor.startProcess(BaseBusinessProcessor.java:203)
    at net.acs.sdd.scvv.bo.command.StartProcessCommand.execute(StartProcessCommand.java:25)
    at net.acs.sdd.pkop.bo.command.GnivcRtuDecisionCommand.execute(GnivcRtuDecisionCommand.java:49)
    at net.acs.sdd.scvv.bo.MessageDispatcher.processInputMessageObject(MessageDispatcher.java:175)
    at net.acs.sdd.scvv.bo.MessageDispatcher.processInputMessage(MessageDispatcher.java:130)
    at net.acs.sdd.scvv.bo.MessageDispatcher.processInputMessage(MessageDispatcher.java:101)
    at net.acs.sdd.scvv.bo.RollbackMessageDispatcher.processInputMessage(RollbackMessageDispatcher.java:55)
    at net.acs.sdd.scvv.transport.BaseMessageReceiver.processInputMessage(BaseMessageReceiver.java:66)
    at net.acs.sdd.scvv.transport.SCVVMessageReceiver.onMessageInternal(SCVVMessageReceiver.java:135)
    at net.acs.sdd.scvv.transport.BaseMessageReceiver.onMessage(BaseMessageReceiver.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor119.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:317)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:183)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:260)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:94)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:204)
    at $Proxy10.onMessage(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doInvokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:562)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.invokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:500)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doExecuteListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:468)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.doReceiveAndExecute(AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.java:325)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.receiveAndExecute(AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.java:243)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.invokeListener(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:1096)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.executeOngoingLoop(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:1088)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.run(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:985)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: javax.resource.ResourceException: SystemException: Failed to add the resource due to error in the resource : oracle.jdbc.xa.OracleXAException errorcode : -7
    at oracle.oc4j.sql.spi.ManagedConnectionImpl.setupTransaction(ManagedConnectionImpl.java:841)
    at oracle.oc4j.sql.spi.ConnectionHandle.oc4j_intercept(ConnectionHandle.java:305)
    at oracle_jdbc_driver_LogicalConnection_Proxy.prepareStatement()
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.getPreparedStatement(AbstractBatcher.java:534)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.getPreparedStatement(AbstractBatcher.java:452)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.prepareQueryStatement(AbstractBatcher.java:161)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.prepareQueryStatement(Loader.java:1573)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:696)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:259)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2228)
    ... 54 more
Caused by: javax.resource.ResourceException: SystemException: Failed to add the resource due to error in the resource : oracle.jdbc.xa.OracleXAException errorcode : -7
    at com.evermind.server.connector.ConnectionContext.setupForJTATransaction(ConnectionContext.java:378)
    at com.evermind.server.connector.ConnectionContext.setupForTransaction(ConnectionContext.java:303)
    at com.evermind.server.connector.ConnectionContext.setupForTransaction(ConnectionContext.java:288)
    at com.evermind.server.connector.ApplicationConnectionManager.lazyEnlist(ApplicationConnectionManager.java:2149)
    at oracle.j2ee.connector.OracleConnectionManager.lazyEnlist(OracleConnectionManager.java:312)
    at oracle.oc4j.sql.spi.ManagedConnectionFactoryImpl.enlist(ManagedConnectionFactoryImpl.java:532)
    at oracle.oc4j.sql.spi.ManagedConnectionImpl.setupTransaction(ManagedConnectionImpl.java:839)
    ... 63 more
```

And I don't know how to find any connection with that 'errorcode : -7'

I went into OracleXAException to find, at least some decription. And there is

public static final int XA_HEURCOM = 7;
and if I found correct this is [description](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/transaction/xa/XAException.html#XA_HEURCOM)  of my error.

But it doesn't help me.

Which way should I follow to find the root of that exception, Could some help me with that?

P.S.

And, also I want to add, that we have working application.That exception happened in the middle of a day and after that were also about 10 exceptions like that but after them there were not exceptions in log.

Comment: would help to see the sql code too.

Comment: Actually, I don't know which query should be executed, because the line ' net.acs.sdd.scvv.bo.BaseBusinessProcessor.startProcess(BaseBusinessProcessor.java:209)'  its the common line which generates different values for different query. And 'org.jbpm.pvm' is not our library, which generates exception

Comment: then its better to see a small reproducer of this exception. otherwise I can not ansswer